# Add Value based on condition in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

If Current value is > Previous Value (value.shift(-1)) Then add value to df[''].

Start from bottom to top.  Please see my expecting dataframe to see what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

We can  [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) checking condition with [`groupby.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html).

```
df2=df.sort_values('timestamp')
blocks=df2.groupby('id')['value'].diff(-1).ge(0).cumsum()
df['finalvalue']=df2['value'].mask(blocks.ne(0), 
                                   df2.groupby(['id',blocks])['value'].cumsum())
print(df)
```

---

```
            timestamp       id  value  finalvalue
0 2020-02-16 03:05:57  device1   1000        4100
1 2020-02-16 02:05:33  device1    900        3100
2 2020-02-16 01:05:08  device1    700        2200
3 2020-02-16 00:04:44  device1    300        1500
4 2020-02-15 23:04:19  device1   1200        1200
5 2020-02-15 22:03:55  device1    800         800
6 2020-02-15 21:03:29  device1    400         400
7 2020-02-15 20:03:04  device1    200         200
8 2020-02-15 19:02:39  device1    100         100
9 2020-02-15 18:02:14  device1      0           0
```

Comment: you could remove 'id' of groupby if you don't want consider it